# StringTemplate4 if conditional with length

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I need to generate the following kinds of code with StringTemplate4:

```
methodFoo0(Connection conn);
methodFoo1(Connection conn, int arg1);
methodFoo2(Connection conn, int arg1, int arg2); 

etc.
```

The "Connection conn" part is always present so I am only passing the method name and the rest of the arguments to my ST template. My template looks as follows:

```
<methodName>(Connection conn, <args; separator=", ">);
```

This works but produces an extra comma when there are no arguments at all (except conn):

```
methodFoo0(Connection conn,);
```

To eliminate the extra comma I tried using the **if** conditional and the **length** ST4 function but I couldn't get it to work although I tried various combos like the following:

```
<methodName>(Connection conn <if (length(fieldsInFind) \> 0)>,<else><endif><fieldsInFind; separator=", ">)
```

... and others which they all failed with some parsing-related error (*mismatched input*).

In the end, I gave up and resorted to passing a **comma** parameter to the template which is either "," or the empty string "" based on pre-rendering logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the presence of the second parameter using `<if (fieldsInFind)>` and only pass this to the template if its size is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

The extra comma is not produced by the separator but it is the one you already typed after `Connection conn,`.

You do the following:

`<methodName>(Connection conn<if(args)>,<args; separator=", "><endif>)`

Notice the comma after the conn is only placed if there are in fact more arguments.